# Jena - How to know whether a specific resource is in the model?

Tags: resources, jena

I am trying to discover whether I had a specific resource in the model. For that I am using:

```
model.getResource("example")
```

Checking the doc, this method behaves exactly as createResource. Then, even if it is not in the model, I will get a new resource.

How can I check I have the resource avoiding its creation when it's not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this link [Interface Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) is useful.

Comment: After researching a little bit I have found the next way. I don't know if this is really the best way to achieve it, but works:

    Resource toSearch = ResourceFactory.createResource("example");
    if(!model.containsResource(toSearch))...;

Comment: If it is solved then post an answer and accept it, so the next person with the same issue will find the answer, you also get a badge! :)

Comment: @Boaz.Jan Thank you very much for your suggestion, but the system does not allow me to post now. I have to wait 8 hours. I'll do afterwards! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Jena, `Resource` objects by themselves are not *in* the model. The model only contains *triples* - `Statement` objects containing a subject, predicate and object (usually abbreviated SPO). Any one of S, P or O can be a resource (noting that a `Property` is a sub-type of `Resource` in Jena and in the RDF standard). So you need to refine your question from "does this model contain this resource" to either:

- does model M contain resource R as a subject?
- does model M contain resource R as a subject, predicate or object?

This can be achieved as:

```
Resource r = ... ;
Model m = ... ;

// does m contain r as a subject?
if (m.contains( r, null, (RDFNode) null )) {
  ..
}

// does m contain r as s, p or o?
if (m.containsResource( r )) {
  ..
}
```

Incidentally, in your code sample you have

```
model.getResource("example")
```

This returns a `Resource` object corresponding to the given URI, but does not side-effect the triples in the model. This is the reason that `Model` has both `getResource` and `createResource` - get is potentially slightly more efficient since it re-uses resource objects, but the semantics are essentially identical. However, the argument you pass to `getResource` or `createResource` **should be a URI**. You are borrowing trouble from the future if you start using tokens like `"example"` in place of full URI's, so I would advise stopping this bad habit before you get comfortable with it!

Comment: Thank you very much. That's definitely the solution. About the bad habit, don't worry, in my development I'm using real URIs. I just used "example" because it didn't matter this time.

Comment: Checking the solution: there are several contains which fit with r, null, null. I would rather suggest:
model.contains(resource, null, (RDFNode)null)

Comment: Good catch. Yes, it's a pain that the method signature for `contains()` is liberal enough to require a cast on the `object` argument, but it's a design decision that was made a long time ago in Jena's early history and would be too disruptive to change now.

Comment: This answer needs an update. `getResource` now behaves same as `createResource`: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 3):

After researching a little bit I have found the next way. I don't know if this is really the best way to achieve it, but works:

```
Resource toSearch = ResourceFactory.createResource("example");
if(!model.containsResource(toSearch))...;
```

Comment: This is a right answer but I have to wait 2 days to mark it as right